# Perl File Globbing Oddities

Tags: perl, glob, built-in

I'm writing a script that will loop through a range of numbers, build a glob pattern, and test if a file exists in a directory based on the glob.

The images are Nascar car number images, and follow the the following pattern:

```
1_EARNHARDTGANASSI_256.TGA
2_PENSKERACING_256.TGA
```

Here is a snippet of the script that I am using:

```
foreach $currCarNum (0..101) {  
    if (glob("//headshot01/CARS/${currCarNum}_*_256.TGA")) {    
        print("Car image $currCarNum exists\n");
    } else {
        print("Car image $currCarNum doesn't exist\n");
    }   
}
```

The problem I'm having, is that images that exist in the directory, and that should match the file glob pattern do not.

For example, the file with the following name returns as not existing:

```
2_PENSKERACING_256.TGA
```

Whereas, the following returns as existing:

```
1_EARNHARDTGANASSI_256.TGA
```

If I use the same file glob pattern in DOS or Cygwin, both files are listed properly.

Are file glob patterns interpreted differently in Perl?  Is there something I am missing?

Comment: See [`perldoc -f glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)

Comment: @Brad: perlop seems to have a better explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the results returned in a list format instead of a scalar format.  Try this for your if statement, it worked for me when I tested it.

```
if (my @arr = glob("//headshot01/CARS/${currCarNum}_*_256.TGA")) {
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I really need to learn Perl better before I go hacking away. :)

Answer (score 1):

From [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> A (file)glob evaluates its (embedded)
>   argument only when it is starting a
>   new list. All values must be read
>   before it will start over. In list
>   context, this isn't important because
>   you automatically get them all anyway.
>   However, in scalar context the
>   operator returns the next value each
>   time it's called, or **undef when the
>   list has run out**.